# Browserify failing to compile react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browserify

This is the gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
    babel = require('gulp-babel'),
    babelify = require("babelify");

gulp.task('js', function () {
  gulp.src(config.paths.js.src)
    .pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals : true,
        debug : true
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.js.dest))
});
```

In package.json I have added:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["react"] }]]
}
```

And this is the file with react:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Overlay message="TEST" />,
  document.getElementById('content')
 );
```

finally, the error is:

```
components/main-component.js:15
            <div class="overlay">
            ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
    at wrapWithPluginError (/home/novak/Documents/myProjects/OpenWorld/node_modules/gulp-browserify/index.js:44:1
```

Note: I am not using ES2015, just normal js.

I have tried a lot of things to put into the gulp task, but it always gives me some error. Could anybody advise me how to make this work please?

Some more sources:
main-component.js:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Print = require('./main-template');

var Overlay = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { show: false };
    },
    render: function() {
        if (!this.state.show) {
            return;
        }
        return(
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="content">
                    <Print message="{this.props.message}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Overlay message="TEST" />,
  document.getElementById('game-content')
 );

module.exports = Overlay;
```

Comment: maybe a JSX problem... can you show the code of `main-component.js` ?

Comment: @oliv37 I have added the source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `.jsx` to `.js` since Browser don't know the `JSX`. So you need to transform it before.

**Steps to covert `jsx` to `js`:**

Make sure that you have installed

1. `gulp-babel`
2. `babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx`

by

```
npm install gulp-babel babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

Then in your `gulp` file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task("babel", function(){
    return gulp.src("src to jsx/*.jsx").
        pipe(babel({
            plugins: ['transform-react-jsx']
        })).
        pipe(gulp.dest("src to js/*.js"));
});
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution within one gulp task. But I got it working using the snippet you have provided - I compile the jsx to js files and in my code I require the js files.

Comment: So where you stuck now?

Comment: Gulp compiles it fine, but in browser: I got 'Failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js.map', so I googled and disabled some settings in chrome settings, now I get: 'Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.', but that might be my syntax error somewhere, though I don't see it (the main-component.js file I posted)

Comment: change this `message="{this.props.message}"` to `message={this.props.message}`. It may be not be error you are getting. Check the line number for error to proceed